# File Uploads with Django + HTML Forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm pretty thoroughly confused by this, I'm not entirely sure where I'm supposed to connect my form and view so to speak.

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Above is my model for the form--below is the view.

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = "Form is valid"
        else:
            response = "Failed to upload"
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>
            Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
            <input type="text" name="title" size="30">
            <input name="file" type="file" size="40">
            </p>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I had some of my own code but after seeing a couple of other Stack Overflow questions and perusing the documentation I simplified it.  (The model and view function can be found in this thread [File upload with Django: Invalid form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753087/file-upload-with-django-invalid-form))

I'm really lost on how I'm supposed to connect these from form to view to server.  I've set my settings so that there is indeed a media root where these files should supposedly go.  I'm feeling that I may just have the wrong kind of input type in the form.

I've been getting the Failed to Upload response meaning that the form is somehow invalid.  I just don't really know how this exactly comes together.

Comment: Do you have a URL for `upload` in your urls.py file?  Here's an intro to that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls

Comment: Yes, I do.  The /upload/ endpoint directs to the upload_file view function

Comment: After response = "Failed to upload", print form.errors, paste the result please. You shouldn't have such a poor form template, it doesn't support errors nor is it able to re-use posted values. This is how to make a form template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Comment: I was getting a field is required error, so the text field I specified was apparently required and I had been leaving it blank. I've been scouring for a documentation like the one you pasted jpic, I'll give that a look, hopefully I can get some more stuff cleared up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/) if you have a model below it. So you will just need to do form.save() inside your view to save an object.

Comment: Looks like this answer is outdated. Here's the current link for [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/).